# Is keystore file (server.jks), my private key file?

Tags: tls, certificates, java

My task is to convert `.p7b` to `.pfx`. It would be great, if you could provide me some pointers.

Below are the steps I used to generate the `.p7b` file:

1. I generated a `.jks` (java keystore) file using below command

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin>keytool -genkey -alias serverkey -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\server\production\ssl\Server.jks -keysize 2048
   ```
2. From keystore file I created a CSR using following command

   ```
   keytool -certreq -alias serverkey -file ServerCSR.csr -keystore Server.jks
   ```
3. I provided this `.CSR` file to a local CA certificate authority. They
   provided me the certificate in `.p7b` format

I have two questions:

1. And how we can convert `.p7b` file into `.pfx` format ?
2. Is keystore file (`server.jks`), my private key file which is being asked to convert on various available links on google?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did `keytool genkey` in the file `server.jks` so that file contains your private key. What you need to do is, first add your cert (chain) to the JKS, THEN convert the JKS to "PFX". The p7b by itself does not contain sufficient information.

The `.p7b` from the CA contains the cert for your server, and may contain other "chain" or "intermediate" certs which your server cert depends on. You say this cert is from a "local CA"; is that CA itself delegated from a well-known "root" CA like Verisign? If not, if the local CA has its own root, is that root already added to the `cacerts` and/or `jssecacerts` file in your `JAVA_HOME/lib/security`? (If you or other users on your system have been interacting with systems using this CA and it has a private root, you likely have already needed to add it to a truststore, but not necessarily the standard one.)

IF the chain the CA gave you uses a root that is either already in the Java-distributed `cacerts` like Verisign or has been added to `cacerts` on your specific system, run

```
keytool -keystore server.jks -alias serverkey -import -file whatever.p7b -trustcacerts
```

The response should be "Certificate reply was installed in keystore". If it says "Certificate was added to keystore" that is actually an error even though it doesn't say so.
Then convert to PKCS#12, which is the actual standard Microsoft and some other people call PFX, as one line but broken for posting:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.jks -destkeystore server.pfx 
-deststoretype pkcs12 -srcalias serverkey
```

On the first step, if the needed root (or anchor) isn't in `cacerts` (well-known or already added) but at least one CA cert is in the p7b, `keytool` will display info about the "top-level" certificate and ask `Install reply anyway?`; just answer "yes". If anything more complicated is wrong, give details.